# Parse json from array values

Tags: python

I currently pass the "buttons" to somefunction as two separate parameters, like so:

```
button1 = {"title": "foo", "url": "bar" /.../ }
button2 = {"title": "foo", "url": "bar" /.../ }
somefunction(id, text, button1, button2)

def somefunction(recipient_id, message_text, button1, button2):
    data = json.dumps({
        "recipient": {
            "id": recipient_id
        },
        "message": {
            "attachment": {
                "type": "template",
                "payload": {
                    "template_type": "button",
                    "text" : message_text,
                    "buttons" : [
                        {
                            "type" : button1["type"],
                            "url" : button1["url"],
                            "title" : button1["title"]
                        },
                        {
                            "type" : button2["type"],
                            "title" : button2["title"],
                            "payload" : button2["payload"]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    })
```

How can I rewrite the json.dumps in somefunction so that I can send the buttons as one parameter like below? I.e. how can I iterate through 'buttons' and parse the correct json-dumps?

```
buttons = {
   {"title": "foo", "url": "bar" /.../ },
   {"title": "foo", "url": "bar" /.../ }
}
somefunction(id, text, buttons)
```

Comment: Use `[]` as the outer brackets for `buttons`.

Answer (score 0):

You can send a JSON containing a list of 'buttons':

```
{
   "buttons" :
   [
      {"title": "foo", "url": "bar" /.../ },
      {"title": "foo", "url": "bar" /.../ }
   ]
}
```

and then parse it in `somefunction`

Answer (score 0):

You could use keyword-only arguments (only works if you are using python 3) along with keyword-argument unpacking to achieve this:

```
import json
def somefunction(recipient_id, message_text, *, button1, button2):
    return json.dumps({
        "recipient": {
            "id": recipient_id
        },
        "message": {
            "attachment": {
                "type": "template",
                "payload": {
                    "template_type": "button",
                    "text" : message_text,
                    "buttons" : [
                        {
                            "type" : button1["type"],
                            "url" : button1["url"],
                            "title" : button1["title"]
                        },
                        {
                            "type" : button2["type"],
                            "title" : button2["title"],
                            "payload" : button2["payload"]
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    })

buttons = {
    'button1' : {"title": "foo", "url": "bar", "type": "baz" },
    'button2' : {"title": "foo", "url": "bar", "type": "type2", "payload": "aLOT"}
}

x = somefunction("ID", "text", **buttons)
```

**Notice** I changed your function to return the json.dumps for my own debugging purposes.

See the documentation for these constructs here:

https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3102/
https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists